# User Control not giving the real width and height

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, graphics

I have add a user control and resize it to 300 x 300 in the control designer.
I declared it in the top so that I can use it through out my entire code but it gives me the wrong width of the control but when I declare it in the event itself I get the right width.

Ex:

```
Public Class UserControl1

Dim A As Integer = Me.Width

Private Sub UserControl1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click

    Dim B As Integer = Me.Width

    MsgBox("A = " & A & " " & "and" & "  " & "B = " & B)

End Sub
```

End Class

I named the Variables A and B but A gives me 150 and B gives me 300

[A = 150 and B = 300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvnmQ.jpg)

Can anyone please explain this to me??? Thanks

Comment: `A` is set to the width when the object is first constructed, before any properties like `Width` have been modified by any consuming code.  `B` is set when the control is clicked, after the control has been fully loaded.

Comment: Thank you Steven. Now I understand more clearly. Thanks again.

Comment: Why was my question and header changed to something that have no  relevance  to my problem. All I wanted to know was why the two values are different and @Steven Doggart explained it to me.Steven understood what I wanted to know . So why edit it ???

Comment: Usually, the edit functionality on StackOverflow works great and adds value by allowing other users to improve the wording of your question for you.  This is a rare case of it going wrong and your original intent being lost in the edit.  You can always edit your own question and revert it back to the way you want it, so it's not that big of a deal.  If you're unhappy with an edit, just change it back.  I went ahead and reverted it back to your original question for you.

Comment: Thanks for changing it back. Thought it was the moderator changing the post and would be no use off me to change it because he would just change it again. Did not know that anyone could change it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the values are different is because `A` is set to the width when the object is first constructed, before any properties like `Width` have been modified by any consuming code. `B` is set when the control is clicked, after the control has been fully loaded.

Comment: Tried to give you a up vote but it says I have not enough experience points.